# CSS background Image responsively cover the bottom

Tags: html, css, sass

all! I meet a CSS question. The below picture is the layout of my web page. What I want to implement is component A, B and C keeps unchanged in various sizes of screen, and these components have fixed margin and padding. And D has a background image cover its content, and this background image can responsively cover the D component dose not have any blank space. Sorry to my the English, not native spaker.

[image]

I implement this layout by using Vuetify and nuxtJS, due to the regulation of the company, I cannot upload the code, but I append the similar work that I did.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.a {
  margin: 40px auto;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.b {
  margin: 40px auto;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.c {
  margin: 40px auto;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.d {
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
</body>
```

What I want to implement is that the background colour or image of `D` component can cover to the end of the screen and without leaving any blank space. And it can also responsively designed.

Comment: Can you provide us with what you've done so far? Some code will be appreciate ;)

Comment: Sure, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: I just understood what you're trying to do. If you want the d component to fill all the screen you need to `position: absolute;` it inside a `position: relative;` element, like your entire page box. Example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.a {
  margin: 40px auto;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.b {
  margin: 40px auto;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.c {
  margin: 40px auto;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.a, .b, .c {
  width: 300px;
}

.d {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150x150');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body class="relative">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
</body>
```

I used `z-index:-1;` to bring the d element behind the other elements. I also used `background-size: cover;` to make the background image fill all the empty space. `background-repeat: no-repeat;` to make the image not repeat. Further, you need to use `width` in the absolute positioned element.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should give width to your boxes.

```
.a, .b, .c{
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box; 
    }
    .a{
      margin: 40px auto;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    .b{
      margin: 40px auto;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    .c{
      margin: 40px auto;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: blue;
    }
    .d{
      margin-top: 40px;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: pink;
    }
    .a, .b, .c{
      width: 200px;
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is very close to the result that I want, but could you make the pink colour cover to the bottom of the screen? And I hope this feature can responsively perform.

Comment: @张俊旭 are you saying that D's width and height should have the same ratio as the image? If then it's possible with javascript, get image's height and width and browser width and set D's height. Or just set a height in your .d too.

Comment: No, I want the pink colour cover the whole D and no blank space exist in D.